# How can I avoid writing duplicate Unit Tests for classes that implement the same interface?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010

I'm just getting into unit tests using Visual Studio 2010. I'm wondering if there is a workflow that would allow me to create a series of tests that apply to an Interface and then apply those interface tests to any and all classes that implement the interface.

For example say I have the following interface.

```
public interface IAnimal
{
   public string Name {get;}
   public string Speak();
}
```

I could obviously have a number of classes that implement this interface.

```
public class Dog:IAnimal
{
  public string Name {get{return "Dog";}}
  public string Speak{return "BARK BARK";}
  public bool LickBalls();
}

public class Cat:IAnimal
{
  public string Name {get{return "Cat";}}
  public string Speak{return "MEOW MEOW";}
  public bool Scratch();
}
```

So I'd like to define a series of tests that apply to all `IAnimals`

```
   public TestAnimalName(IAnimal animal)
   {      
       Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullorEmpty(animal.Name));
   }

   public TestAnimalSpeak(IAnimal animal)
   {      
       string sound = animal.Speak();
       Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sound));
   }
```

Then I'd like to define a master `TestAnimal()` method which could be used to test any `IAnimal`.

```
TestAnimal(IAnimal animal)
{
    TestAnimalName(animal);
    TestAnimalSpeak(animal);
}
```

I could then call this `TestAnimal()` method when testing a concrete type of `IAnimal`.

```
[TestMethod]
TestCat()
{
    Cat c = new Cat();
    TestAnimal(c);
}

[TestMethod]
TestDog()
{
    Dog c = new Dog();
    TestAnimal(c);
}
```

Yet when I try to do this in Visual Studio the `Asserts` in the called methods are ignored. I tried to simplify the problem with the method below and found that it passed even though it calls a method that should result in a failure.

```
[TestMethod]
public void AssertInCalledMethod() //this will pass
{
    Assert.IsTrue(true);
    Blah();
}

public void Blah()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(false);
}
```

So how can I avoid writing a lot of duplicate tests for classes that all implement the same interface?

Comment: wow that is busted behavior from VS unit testing.  if you use NUnit it would work as you expect.

Comment: i would say your problem is not writing the tests, those seem reasonable approaches to me.  the problem is the busted behavior in VS unit testing.

Comment: While I don't know the answer, the method "LickBalls" made me LOL.

Comment: So *that* is why Microsoft software has a reputation for being a little buggy. Their unit tests all pass so it's ready to ship, right?

Comment: I don't have a question to the specific problem, but I'd note that I  use this general technique all the time with VS Unit testing and Asserts in called methods generally work fine.  Your problem has to do with a build issue or something your aren't showing.

Comment: One thing you can do here is create a test which uses reflection to find all concrete classes which implement IAnimal, then instatiate them by finding the default constructor (must have a parameterless constructor) and call the TestAnimal on it.   There are some problems with this (all of them are run in the same test for example, but if you have a lot of classes which implement a simple interface, this can save time).  I do this for very simple interfaces of which I might have a couple dozen implementations.

Answer (score 5):

Greg Young's [Hei Hei Grensesnitt](http://github.com/gregoryyoung/grensesnitt) takes a slightly different approach to this problem, which I like. You can write an interface specification:

```
[InterfaceSpecification] 
public class ICanAddTests : AppliesTo<ICanAdd>{ 

    [Test] 
    public void can_add_two_numbers() { 
          Assert.AreEqual(5, sut.Add(2,3)); 
    } 
}
```

... and the framework automatically executes the test for all classes it finds that implement the interface. This is using NUnit, not MSTest, but I think it's a rather clever idea and makes for a very easy workflow.

Comment: What if [some of] my classes do not have parameterless constructor? I cant find an example of GrensesnittObjectLocator usage.

Answer (score 1):

Your final code snippet:

```
[TestMethod]
public void AssertInCalledMethod() //this will pass
{
    Assert.IsTrue(true);
    Blah();
}

public void Blah()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(false);
}
```

fails like it's meant to on my computer. Sometimes visual studio can get confused about old dlls and run old versions of your tests (or libraries being tested), if you rename the test method does that rename reflect itself in the test runner?

P.S. I think your approach with `TestAnimal(IAnimal animal)` is ideal...

Comment: Humm yeah i don't know what was going on before. Now I ran it again and AssertInCalledMethod returned failed as it should. So it seems like the process I described above is the right answer?

Comment: Yep - just create whatever utility methods make sense for the abstractions you want to work with. I do this (for example) for things like asserting that two Lists are equal (and printing the differences nicely)